# Links and buttons don't display correctly in Hotmail (CSS, HTML)

Tags: email, html-email, hotmail

I've found that the emails I send from my application have their links (whether normal link or button) 'stripped' by Hotmail. Other email providers I've tested like Gmail are fine though. E.g. code like the below...

```
<a href="mydomain/book_request"><b>Book</b></a>
```

... results in Hotmail showing the following text:

[mydomain/book_request]Book

The same happens with buttons that contain links

What is the right HTML/CSS to use?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you prefix your url with `http(s)://`? If you have done that and it didn't change anything try sending an email with only link included, remove everything else and check if it changes anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain/book_request" style='font-weight: bold;">Book</a>
```

You should include a `http://` or `https://` in front of every link. I'm not sure how Hotmail interprets an unstyled `<b>` tag, but it's not the only way to bold text.